# How to send HTML email (in template) from extension?

Tags: email, extension, html-email

I am using the [Email Class](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/development/legacy/libraries/email.html) in an extension to send an email when an entry is saved with a certain status. This all works great and the emails send when they are supposed to.

However, I am looking to enhance this: for the body of the email I would like to be able to pull a template that I have created. I previously had been pasting in my entire HTML email into the extension which works- but this seems impractical, especially when I need to make changes to the email.

Any ideas or pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes Brianne**, you can pull the body of the template in your extension. To achieve this you need to create separate library for parsing the template into your extension. And by loading that library you can access the code of your template into your extension.